Azure Logic app designer - Compose expression extract value from json (How??)
I am in need of some wisdom.
So my logic app works like the following:

"When a HTTP Request is received"
Switch on Path parameters
Parse json -> Scheme (Name: Parse JSON from conversation (Call Metadata))
Compose (Issue)

So the parsed json looks like so:
{
    "body": {
        "id": "1",
        "xxxx2": "Setup",
        "xxxx3": "inbound",
        "xxxx4": "12345678",
        "xxxx5": "",
        "labels": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "externalId": "TestingAndLogid241/Callid-273",
        "xxxxxx6": 4,
        "audiochannel": "cccc",
        "title": "cccc",
    }
}

I want using a compose function to select externalId and return the value "273" as a variable i can use.
I've tried to create a substring expression, but i cannot get it to work for the life of me.
Thank you :)
So i tried playing with the substring function, but couldn't seem to get it working

If you’ve used Parse JSON then you should have dynamic output you can select from in your compose operation.

That was already done, i then want to take the value of the output and only select a part of the whole value

There are a few ways to do that and not fully knowing the ongoing structure of your text, I'd use this approach for the example you've provided in your question ...
last(split(body('Parse_JSON_from_conversation_(Call_Metadata)')?['body']?['externalId'], '-'))

